# Adding parameter to ng-click function inside ng-repeat doesn't seem to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple loop with `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
  <p> {{task.name}}
  <button ng-click="removeTask({{task.id}})">remove</button>
</li>
```

There is a function in the controller `$scope.removeTask(taskID)`.

As far as I know Angular will first render the view and replace interpolated `{{task.id}}` with a number, and then, on click event, will evaluate `ng-click` string.

In this case `ng-click` gets totally what is expected, ie: `ng-click="removeTask(5)".` However... it's not doing anything.

Of course I can write a code to get `task.id` from the `$tasks` array or even the DOM, but this does not seem like the Angular way.

So, how can one add dynamic content to `ng-click` directive inside a `ng-repeat` loop?

Answer (score 757, accepted):

Instead of

```
<button ng-click="removeTask({{task.id}})">remove</button>
```

do this:

```
<button ng-click="removeTask(task.id)">remove</button>
```

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/34/

Comment: +1: this also works if your `ng-click` expression doesn't use brackets, i.e. `ng-click="taskData.currentTaskId = task.id"`

Comment: Thanks Sir..I seen lots of blog but my problem is solved by your solution.

Answer (score 53):

One thing that really hung me up, was when I inspected this html in the browser, instead of seeing it expanded to something like:

```
<button ng-click="removeTask(1234)">remove</button>
```

I saw:

```
<button ng-click="removeTask(task.id)">remove</button>
```

However, the latter works!

This is because you are in the "Angular World", when inside ng-click="" Angular all ready knows about task.id as you are inside it's model. There is no need to use Data binding, as in {{}}.

Further, if you wanted to pass the task object itself, you can like:

```
<button ng-click="removeTask(task)">remove</button>
```

Comment: How would this work if your method is looking for a string?

Comment: @Dinerdo it wouldn't.  to do "removeTask(task)" you would have to change the method to expect to get a task object and get the id property from that object.

Answer (score 10):

Also worth noting, for people who find this in their searches, is this...

```
<div ng-repeat="button in buttons" class="bb-button" ng-click="goTo(button.path)">
  <div class="bb-button-label">{{ button.label }}</div>
  <div class="bb-button-description">{{ button.description }}</div>
</div>
```

Note the value of `ng-click`.  The parameter passed to `goTo()` is a string from a property of the binding object (the `button`), but it is not wrapped in quotes.  Looks like AngularJS handles that for us.  I got hung up on that for a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

this works. thanks. I am injecting custom html and compile it using angular in the controller.

```
        var tableContent= '<div>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></div>' 
                            +'<div class="table-heading">'
                            +    '<div class="table-col">Customer ID</div>'
                           + ' <div class="table-col" ng-click="vm.openDialog(c.CustomerId)">{{c.CustomerId}}</div>';

            $timeout(function () {
            var linkingFunction = $compile(tableContent);
            var elem = linkingFunction($scope);

            // You can then use the DOM element like normal.
            jQuery(tablePanel).append(elem);

            console.log("timeout");
        },100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are excellent. You can look at the following full code example so that you could exactly know how to use

```js
   var app = angular.module('hyperCrudApp', []);

   app.controller('usersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)

         $scope.users = response.data;
          $scope.setKey = function (userId){
              alert(userId)
              if(localStorage){
                localStorage.setItem("userId", userId)
              } else {
                alert("No support of localStorage")
                return
              }
          }//function closed  
     });
   });
```

```css
      #header{
       color: green;
       font-weight: bold;
      }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>HyperCrud</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- NAVBAR STARTS -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HyperCrud</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apps<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="/qAlarm/details/">qAlarm &raquo;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/YtEdit/details/">YtEdit &raquo;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/GWeather/details/">GWeather &raquo;</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="/WadStore/details/">WadStore &raquo;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/chatsAll/details/">chatsAll</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/login/">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="/register/">Register</a></li>
              <li><a href="/services/">Services<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!--NAVBAR ENDS-->
  <br>
  <br>

  <div ng-app="hyperCrudApp" ng-controller="usersCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <center>
        <h1 id="header"> Users </h1>
      </center>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" >
        <!--ITERATING USERS LIST-->
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="user in users">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <center>
           <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/users-2/512/User_1-512.png" alt="Image - {{user.name}}" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width: 100px">
           <hr>
          </center>
          <div class="caption">
           <center>
             <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
             <p>{{user.email}}</p>
             <p>+91 {{user.phone}}</p>
             <p>{{user.address.city}}</p>
            </center>
          </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="/users/delete/{{user.id}}/" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="setKey(user.id)">DELETE</a>
                <a href="/users/update/{{user.id}}/" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="setKey(user.id)">UPDATE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="/regiser/">
             <img src="http://img.bhs4.com/b7/b/b7b76402439268b532e3429b3f1d1db0b28651d5_large.jpg" alt="Register Image" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width: 100%">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!--ROW ENDS-->
  </div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div  ng-repeat="scannedDevice in ScanResult">
        <!--GridStarts-->
          <div >
              <img ng-src={{'./assets/img/PlaceHolder/Test.png'}} 
                   <!--Pass Param-->
                   ng-click="connectDevice(scannedDevice.id)"
                   altSrc="{{'./assets/img/PlaceHolder/user_place_holder.png'}}" 
                   onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">
           </div>    
 </div>
```

Java Script:

```
   //Global Variables
    var  ANGULAR_APP = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

    ANGULAR_APP .controller('TestCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {

      //Variables
      $scope.ScanResult = [];

      //Pass Parameter
      $scope.connectDevice = function(deviceID) {
            alert("Connecting : "+deviceID );
        };
     }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ng repeat with ng click function and to append with slider

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.employees = [
            { 'id': '001', 'name': 'Alpha', 'joinDate': '05/17/2015', 'age': 37 },
            { 'id': '002', 'name': 'Bravo', 'joinDate': '03/25/2016', 'age': 27 },
            { 'id': '003', 'name': 'Charlie', 'joinDate': '09/11/2015', 'age': 29 },
            { 'id': '004', 'name': 'Delta', 'joinDate': '09/11/2015', 'age': 19 },
            { 'id': '005', 'name': 'Echo', 'joinDate': '03/09/2014', 'age': 32 }
        ]

            //This will hide the DIV by default.
                $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.ShowHide = function () {
                //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
                $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
            }
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" ng-click="ShowHide()" /> checkbox1
<div id="mixedSlider">
                    <div class="MS-content">
                        <div class="item"  ng-repeat="emps in employees"  ng-show = "IsVisible">
                          <div class="subitem">
        <p>{{emps.id}}</p>
        <p>{{emps.name}}</p>
        <p>{{emps.age}}</p>
        </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="MS-controls">
                        <button class="MS-left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        <button class="MS-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/multislider.js"></script> 
<script>

        $('#mixedSlider').multislider({
            duration: 750,
            interval: false
        });
</script>
```