# AngularJS : call a Controller method with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angularJs application, all of data are loaded and displayed perfectly, but by clicking on delete prize button nothing happen. I use breakpoint and `alert()` in my `deletePrize()` method, but never this function not called and controls not enter to this function

I have a route in angularjs module like this:

```
...
            .when('/prizes', {templateUrl: '/assets/views/prizes/list.html', controller: PrizeListController})
...
```

and my controller:

```
 function PrizeListController($scope, Prize) {
    $scope.prizes = Prize.query();

    $scope.deletePrize = function (id) {

        alert('in delete method');
        Prize.delete({prizeId: id}, function () {
            toastr.success("جایزه حذف شد!");
            $location.path('/prizes');
        }, function () {
            toastr.error("خطا در عملیات");
        });
    };
}
```

and my partial HTML file:

```
  <h2>
    جوایز
    <button onclick="window.location='#/prizes/new'" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left">ایجاد جایزه</button>
</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            title
        </td>
        <td>
            description
        </td>
        <td>
            score value
        </td>
        <td>
            real value
        </td>
        <td>
            action
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="prize in prizes">
        <td><a href="#/prizes/{{prize.id}}">{{prize.title}}</a></td>
        <td>{{prize.description}}</td>
        <td>{{prize.scoreValue}}</td>
        <td>{{prize.realValue}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deletePrize({{prize.id}})">حذف</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926) replacing `deletePrize({{prize.id}})` with `deletePrize(prize.id)` does not resolve my problem

Comment: replacing `deletePrize({{prize.id}})` with `deletePrize(prize.id)` does not resolve my problem

Comment: انظر إلى هذا ، لعله يفيدك . http://blogs.softfluent.com/post/2014/01/26/Un-exemple-de-CRUD-avec-AngularJS-et-ASPNET-MVC-et-Web-API.aspx