# ng-click doesn't change value in HTML when in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I don't know if this is a problem with AngularJS, or my understanding.

In my app, I have an `ng-repeat` and I need to keep track of the active `$index`, which can be changed when you click on another item. So I thought I would do something like:

```
<body ng-init="active = -1">
    <span ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind="item" ng-click="active = $index"></span>
</body>
```

But this does not work; I know if I change the `ng-click` to `ng-click="select($index)` and apply the change in my controller, this would work. But I'd like to know why the implementation above doesn't work.

Interestingly, if you don't have an `ng-repeat`, this DOES work, i.e:

```
<body ng-init="active = -1">
    <span ng-click="active = 0">Item 1</span>
    <span ng-click="active = 1">Item 2</span>
    ...
</body>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hsVJacgwuH8q6HOL855J) of these two scenarios. Why?

Comment: So the solution seems to be "ng-click="$parent.badClick = $index""

Comment: @MarvinSmit, yeah I was reading the page. Actually, I like the solution by Kalhano better since it doesn't rely on $parent and the problems mentioned there.

Comment: another possible one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-seems-not-to-work

Comment: @E.H.B, thanks. But i really like the answer below, since I am only updating active index and I rather keep it within the HTML page itself

Comment: @Kousha yes, that's a really good one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix that like below,

in HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-click="x.badClick = $index"> // x.badClick
```

on controller

```
$scope.x = {};
```

thats because its create new scope for each repeat, [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) ,,

reference said ,

`Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current`

if u do like `x.badClick`  , `x` is not in the ng-repeat scopes, so it will check the `x` in next top scope, if u need more, check about `prototypical inheritance` here is a good demonstration , [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

---

you can refer the parent properties by using `$parent` also, so this will also work,

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-click="$parent.badClick = $index">
```