# How do I append a variable value to an event call in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code in the html. In the ng-click="inbox.showView('in: {{category|lowercase}}')" the double braces is not working because it is being considered as a string and not as a variable.

How do I ensure I have the category value in the ng-click event?

```
<li ng-repeat="category in inbox.categories track by $index">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="left-row" ng-click="inbox.showView('in: {{category|lowercase}}')" target="_self">
                                        <div class="leftcolumn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                                        <div class="leftcolumn2">{{category}}</div>
                                        <div class="leftcolumn3 email-time" ng-bind="inbox.messageCounts.socialCount"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
```

Comment: ng-click="inbox.showView[category]"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-seems-not-to-work

answers my question

Comment: So you got your answer..

Answer (score 0):

In the controller:

```
$scope.inbox = {
                categories: ['Name', 'Test'],
                showView : function(variable) {
                    **console.log(variable);**
                }
            };
```

In the HTML given the parameter for showView function is object,, hence pass like the below inbox.showView({'in': (category | lowercase) })

```
<li ng-repeat="category in inbox.categories track by $index">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="left-row" ng-click="inbox.showView({'in': (category | lowercase) })" target="_self">
                    <div class="leftcolumn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                    <div class="leftcolumn2">{{category}}</div>
                    <div class="leftcolumn3 email-time" ng-bind="inbox.messageCounts.socialCount"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Comment: ng-click="inbox.showView({'in': (category | lowercase) })" no event fired

Comment: on clicking the name it will invoke the function "showView" of the inbox object, which is given in the controller. refer the controller code.