# Angularjs ng-click inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load a list of clickable news feed URLs in a dropdown-menu. When I use fixed addresses in view, it works fine but when I populate the addresses using controller, dropdown menu is fine but ng-click doesn't work as expected.

Here is jsfiddle of working version:http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/b8Wcz/

**This code works:**

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/45910/rss.xml';loadFeed($event)">ABC News</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss';loadFeed($event);">CNN</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

controller code:

```
var App = angular.module('RSSFeedApp', []);

App.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope', 'FeedService', function ($scope, Feed) {
    $scope.loadButonText = "Select news channel";
    $scope.loadFeed = function (e) {
        Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function (res) {
            $scope.loadButonText = angular.element(e.target).text();
            $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        });
    }


App.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        parseFeed: function (url) {
            return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
        }
    }

}]);
```

**This code does not:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ng-repeat =" newsChannel in channels">
  <a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='{{newsChannel.src}}';loadFeed($event)">{{newsChannel.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

controller code:

```
App.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope', 'FeedService', function ($scope, Feed) {
    $scope.loadButonText = "Select news channel";
    $scope.loadFeed = function (e) {
        Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function (res) {
            $scope.loadButonText = angular.element(e.target).text();
            $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        });
    }

$scope.channels = [
        {
            'src': 'http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/45910/rss.xml',
            'title': 'ABC News'
        },
        {
            'src': 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss',
            'title': 'CNN'
        }
    ];

}]);


App.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        parseFeed: function (url) {
            return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
        }
    }

}]);
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of null

Any idea why the $scope.feedSrc doesn't get the feedSrc url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Added another parameter to loadFeed method.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ng-repeat =" newsChannel in channels">
  <a href="#" ng-click="loadFeed($event,newsChannel.src)">{{newsChannel.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the controller's new version:

```
App.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope', 'FeedService', function ($scope, Feed) {
    $scope.loadButonText = "Select news channel";
    $scope.loadFeed = function (e, feedUrl) {
        Feed.parseFeed(feedUrl).then(function (res) {
            $scope.loadButonText = angular.element(e.target).text();
            $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        });
    }
    $scope.channels = [
        {
            'src': 'http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/45910/rss.xml',
            'title': 'ABC News'
        },
        {
            'src': 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss',
            'title': 'CNN'
        }
    ];

}]);
```

thanks to this post: [ng-click inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-seems-not-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

So I recommend using $parent for this. ng-repeat has it's own scope so when you say "feedSrc" it is looking on the ng-repeat scope for that data. "newsChannel" is available because that gets added by ng repeat but you will notice that is never added to your parent controller's $scope.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ng-repeat =" newsChannel in channels">
     <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.feedSrc='{{newsChannel.src}}';$parent.loadFeed($event)">{{newsChannel.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As an aside, you might consider not doing assignments in the view like that, it is generally preferable to only assign variables in the controller and make sure that your HTML is *read only*

Comment: I had the same guess about scopes but even this change doesn't work. same error

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle link of the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/b8Wcz/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you are passing arguments to your ng-click:

```
ng-click="$parent.feedSrc='{{newsChannel.src}}';..."
```

You don't need to wrap the prperty in handlebars...

```
ng-click="$parent.feedSrc='newsChannel.src';..."
```

should fix your problem.