# Access rendered element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to accesss into a rendered element from AngularJs. Basically I would like to do something like this:

**app.js**

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('project', []);
**var data = '${renderedElement}';**

  app.controller('ProjectController', function(){
  .....
  });


})();
```

If I put this code directly into the html it works... but I would like to put it into a proper app.js.

Does someone have an idea??Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you intend to do, but you probably need a directive for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you would like to access a rendered element in AngularJS? As far as I know you can use jQuery: http://makandracards.com/makandra/15851-angularjs-access-the-scope-for-a-rendered-dom-element

But you should be able to do this within AngularJS as well. An example to add a remove button inside a ng-repeat: 
[Adding parameter to ng-click function inside ng-repeat doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-seems-not-to-work)