# Angular JS ng-click with arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose my html looks like

```
 <h2>Unapproved Users<span class="badge">12</span></h2>
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="user in unApprovedUsers">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{user.Name}} <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ApproveUser({{user.ID}})">Approve</button></li>

</ul>
```

the problem is that approve user cannot be called while sending that argument so how can i send it to the function

Comment: Duplication of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 4):

You do not need the `{{ }}`. You may directly access the user object and it's properties.

```
ng-click="ApproveUser(user.ID)"
```

The double curly braces binding expression(`{{ }}`) tells Angular that it should evaluate the expression inside the double curly braces and insert the result into the DOM in place of the original binding expression .

Since you want to access the user object and pass the property value to your function, you do not need `{{ }}`. You can simply access the object and use the property value and pass it to your method.

Answer (score 4):

Remove brackets `{{  }}`,

```
ng-click="ApproveUser(user.ID)"
```