# How do I resolve this syntax error caused by .?

Tags: angularjs

The error message I am getting is:

> Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 23 of the expression [] starting at [{4}].

The offending html that is causing the issue.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="record in key_table">

         <td ng-repeat="data in record"> 
             {[{ data }]} 
         </td>
         <td>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open({[{ record.KeyNum }]})">Open me!</button>
         </td>
          <td> 
               <button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

The open function in angularjs:

```
 angular.module('KeyManager').controller("KeyController",  function( httpFactory, $uibModal) {
  $ctrl = this; 
  $ctrl.open = function () {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
    templateUrl: 'RecordViewer.html',
    controller: 'RecordViewerInstanceCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    size: "lg",
    resolve: {
      items: function (keyNum) {
          httpFactory.getRecord(keyNum).then(
              function(response) {
                  $ctrl.items = response.data[0];
              },
              function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  $ctrl.items = [];
              }
          );
        return $ctrl.items;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Also, note that I am doing this in a twig file so start and and end symbols have been changed to "{[{" and "}]}" respectively.

Added Information:

I have tried switching the ng-click directive to

```
 "$ctrl.open(record.KeyNum)"
```

but this only prints out the literal string record.KeyNum which is explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work) so @smarx comment is the answer.

Comment: what is $ctrl here?

Comment: Do you maybe just want `$ctrl.open(record.KeyNum)`?

Comment: $ctrl is this and this is the controller that the function lives in. I'll update it so that is more clear. Essentially I am following the example given for [ui- bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: @smarx I don't think that would would work as the record is a object. Once again I'll update to give more context.

Comment: Does it matter that you have an uppercase "K" in the markup and a lowercase "k" in the `resolve` section?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't think it should, but I'll try that out.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I guess it does matter as I have progressed to a different error all together.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry, false positive I forgot save the file from a different attempt.  \*Slaps Forehead\*

Comment: @smarx I tried your suggestion but that literally prints 'record.KeyNum'. Maybe it is twig interfering.

Comment: Did you define the module? angular.module('KeyManager', [])

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Yup, the answer that smarx provided was correct.

Comment: @smarx It's a interesting question. You should to transform your comment in a answer, to allow the author to sign as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `$ctrl.open(record.KeyNum)`.