# How do I know which button was clicked to add as an object to array in the ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I create buttons in `ng-repeat` and set value for each one.
I want to get the value from a selected button and add to array, and, if clicked other buttons, also add the value to the array  as an object.
If clicked again the same button, the value should be removed object from the array.

```
 <div  ng-repeat="room in Rooms">
  ...
    <button id="HR_{{room.Id}}"  value="{{room.Id}}" onclick="AddToCart({{room.Id}})">Add To Cart</button>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var cartlist = [];

function AddToCart(n) {
    var c = $("#cartcount").text();

    cartlist.push({
        Id: n,
    });
    $("#cartcount").text(parseInt(c) + 1);
}
```

this code `onclick="AddToCart({{room.Id}})"` cause an error. I use `ng-click` but I could not get an answer.

Comment: Use `ng-click="functionOnScope(room)"`.

Comment: `onclick="AddToCart(room.Id)"` should work.  you don't need interpolation inside the handler.

Comment: **Bad Practice:** You can pass `event` to `AddToCart` and get the `value` of clicked button using `event.target.value`.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding parameter to ng-click function inside ng-repeat doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this behavior that you need, add or remove with the same button you need to add some logic to check if the element is in the array or not. you can do something like:

HTML:

```
selectedRooms: {{selectedRooms}}

<div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
  <button ng-click="Add_Remove_Room(room.id)">Add / Remove {{room.name}}</button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('tAngularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    $scope.rooms = [
        {id:1, name: "Room #1"},
        {id:2, name: "Room #2"},
        {id:3, name: "Room #3"},
        {id:4, name: "Room #4"}
    ];

    $scope.selectedRooms = [];


    $scope.Add_Remove_Room = function (roomID) {
        var index = $scope.selectedRooms.indexOf(roomID);
        if(index === -1){
            // If is not selected the room -> add it
            $scope.selectedRooms.push(roomID);
        } else {
            // If is  selected the room -> remove it
            $scope.selectedRooms.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered in this question:
[Adding parameter to ng-click function inside ng-repeat doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work)

This was the answer:

Instead of

```
<button ng-click="removeTask({{task.id}})">remove</button>
```

do this:

```
<button ng-click="removeTask(task.id)">remove</button>
```

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/34/

Comment: FYI: The OP is trying to use `onclick` not `ng-click`

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-click and remove the interpolation.

```
<button id="HR_{{room.Id}}"  value="{{room.Id}}" ng-click="AddToCart(room.Id)">Add To Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-click` instead like so:

`ng-click="AddToCart(room.Id)"`