# How can i send index value in function - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How get index of one of two div tag without i don't using ng-repeat?
I tried this but it didn't work;

```
<div ng-click="formselect($index)"></div>
<div ng-click="formselect($index)"></div>
```

Comment: Are you at *least* in the context of an `ng-repeat`?

Comment: That's not `ng-submit`.

Comment: @Makoto There are four div tag, i want to send index of clicked tag

Comment: So like `<div ng-click="formselect(0)"></div><div ng-click="formselect(1)"></div>...`?

Comment: @Phil i doing as you say already, but i want to get index of tags like jquery

Comment: So use `ng-repeat`. There is no `$index` if you're not iterating over something. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges

Comment: @Phil I don't want to list an array, Just i want to get index value of a html tag. I can do this with jQuery, Is not that possible with Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="formselect($event)"></div>
<div ng-click="formselect($event)"></div>
```

JS:

```
var formselect = function(te) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(te.target.className)).indexOf(te.target)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked

```
<div ng-click="formselect('0')"></div>
<div ng-click="formselect('1')"></div>
```

or if you want to load variables from angular js look into this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/34/) or refer to the answer provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: I using array now but what i want to learn is to get index of html tags as like on jQuery, with Angular