# How to know whether checkbox is clicked or not in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am having multiple checkbox as follows

```
moduleNameList = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
<li *ngFor="let module of moduleNameList">
<input [value]="module" type="checkbox"> {{module}}<br>
</li>
```

User can click on any check box, finally once he click on a button I want to know what are values user checked.
Can any one help me on this?
[Click here to see the check boxes with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYJEy.png)

Comment: you can add [(ngmodel)] and (change)="changed($event)" to your input element.

Comment: Hey, how did it go with the answers? Did either help or do you need further assistance? :)

Comment: @AJT_82: thanks for the answer, it worked for me, but [ngValue] is not working instead of it I used [value]

Comment: @KiranKumar Oh, right, you are completely correct! Missed that one, yes ngValue cannot be used here, since we have bound `module.checked` which is a boolean, and even if it wasn't we wouldn't even want to bind a complete object to input (if it worked).

Comment: @AJT_82: I want to use pipe in title of html 
Eg: <td title={{log.CreatedDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"}}></td>but its not working can u help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to make the items to objects, with a new property, for example `checked` as the `ngModel` that toggles the boolean value of `true` when checked and vice versa.

```
moduleNameList=[{name:'test1', checked: false},{name:'test2', checked: false},
                 {name:'test3',checked:false}]
```

template:

```
<li *ngFor="let module of moduleNameList">
  <input [value]="module" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="module.checked"> 
    {{module.name}}
</li>
```

Now you can iterate that array on button click and see which objects have the `checked` property as `true`.

**Edit:** small change as OP noticed my error! We should use `[value]` instead of `[ngValue]`

Answer (score -3):

There are many ways to do this.If we were to use regular jquery approach set your input to

```
<input class="foo" [value]="module" type="checkbox"> {{module}}<br>
```

then you can do this for the click event

```
<script>
        $('.foo').click(function(e)
         {
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(value);
         });
</script>
```

alternatively, take a look at this [Adding parameter to ng-click function inside ng-repeat doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work) that use ng-click