# Get Selected check box value in angular 2 component

Tags: angular

```
<ul class="show-result">
    <li *ngFor="let staff of  allStaffs;">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" >{{ staff.perscode }} | {{ staff.personName }}
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-primary ripple" (click)="addSelectedStaff()">Add</button>
```

where all staff value is

```
allStaffs = [{
               "perscode":23277,
               "personName":"Rahma Said Ali",
               "personCategoryCode":1011,
               "personCategoryName":"A.Pharmacist"
            },
            {
               "perscode":24825,
               "personName":"Zainab Abdul Baqi",
               "personCategoryCode":1011,
               "personCategoryName":"A.Pharmacist"
            } ]
```

How can I get the selected check boxes at Add button click

I have tried to Add this code in angular2 component. I need to know which all are checked. This is not working.

```
addSelectedStaff(){
   console.log("@@ selected options :"+this.selectedOptions);
}

 get selectedOptions() { // right now: ['1','3']
    return this.allStaffs
              .filter(opt => opt.perscode)
              .map(opt => opt.personName)
  }
```

Need to get the entire selected object list.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to add a new property to keep track of which is checked and which not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45170912/6294072

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
  <ul class="show-result">
        <li *ngFor="let staff of  allStaffs;">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{staff.value}}"
                       [(ngModel)]="staff.perscode" >{{ staff.perscode }} | {{ staff.personName }}
             </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ripple" (click)="addSelectedStaff()">Add</button>
```

component.

```
addSelectedStaff() { 
    console.log(this.allStaffs
              .filter(staf => staf.perscode)
              .map(staf=> staf.value))
  }
```

Comment: .filter(staf => staf.checked)  -> there is no checked value in staff. HAve only this 4 values "perscode",
               "personName",
               "personCategoryCode",
               "personCategoryName"

Comment: staff.value -> Can I give staff.perscode here. Tried but returns unselected lalso

Comment: nope. it's working! can you give to me this in plunkr?

Comment: <li *ngFor="let staff of  allStaffs;">
                              
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{staff.perscode}}">
                                 
                                 
                                </li>
        
        Components :  console.log(this.allStaffs
              .filter(staf => staf.perscode)
              .map(staf=> staf.perscode))  : This returns all the Ids

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XHDjs4W1vproK6qdXUo1?p=preview - tried adding can u help in making it work,

Comment: let me know in this code where u will get checked values ? In given answer.